# Trace listener not writing trace information

Tags: c#-4.0, system.diagnostics, tracesource

```
public sealed class Logger
{
    private static TraceSource myTraceSource;

    private Logger()
    {
    }

    public static TraceSource Create()
    {
        if (myTraceSource == null)
            return myTraceSource = new TraceSource("myTraceSource");
        else
            return myTraceSource;
    }

    public static void WriteInfo(string message)
    {
        myTraceSource.TraceEvent(TraceEventType.Information, 0, message);
        myTraceSource.Flush();
    }

    public static void WriteError(Exception ex)
    {
        myTraceSource.TraceEvent(TraceEventType.Error, 1, ex.Message);
        myTraceSource.Flush();            
    }

    public static void WriteError(string message)
    {
        myTraceSource.TraceEvent(TraceEventType.Error, 1, message);
        myTraceSource.Flush();
    }

    public static void WriteWarning(string message)
    {
        myTraceSource.TraceEvent(TraceEventType.Warning, 2, message);
        myTraceSource.Flush();
    }

    public static void AddListener(TraceListener listener)
    {
        myTraceSource.Listeners.Add(listener);
    }

    public static void Close()
    {
        if (myTraceSource != null)
        {
            myTraceSource.Flush();
            myTraceSource.Close();
        }
    }       
}
```

Below is the code to initialize the trace source and add listener

```
Logger.Create();
TextWriterTraceListener myTextListener = new TextWriterTraceListener(LogCompletePath);
Logger.AddListener(myTextListener);
Logger.WriteError("error");
```

Note I have not put the `SytemDiagnostic` tag in `appconfig` as I want to do it in code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Got the answer in another forum. I forgot to mention Source Level and by default it is set to off

```
 return myTraceSource = new TraceSource("myTraceSource", SourceLevels.All);
```

Comment: If anyone is trying to do this with the Mono framework, there appears to be a bug in the TraceSource constructor, so that the SourceLevels you provide may not be used. As a workaround, set myTraceSource.Switch.Level = SourceLevels.All after construction. (I'm using the modified version of Mono 2.6 that ships with the Unity 4.1 game engine.)

Comment: Looks like I'm not the first to find the TraceSource constructor bug: http://mono.1490590.n4.nabble.com/Bug-in-TraceSource-td3201651.html